# Implementing styleOptions into BotChat.App()

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I have a QnA bot. We need it to send a welcome message. To do this, we have moved from window.WebChat.renderWebChat to botchat.app to render the bot. However, I can't find how to add styleOptions to the botchat.app.

Here is the code: for which we need to add style options. Unless it is possible to add the welcome message to the window.WebChat.renderWebChat  code, (which is the 2nd bit of code)?

Which is the best?

```
            var userId = '';
            var userName = '';

            var secret = '';

            var user = {
                id: userId,
                name: userName
            };

            var bot = {
                id: '',
                name: 'QPBotName'
            };


            var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                secret: secret,
                webSocket: true
            });
            
            console.log("Init bot component");
            
            BotChat.App({
                botConnection: botConnection,
                user: user,
                bot: bot,
                resize: 'detect',
                rootwidth: 'Auto',
                
            }, document.getElementById("webchat"));

            const styleOptions = {
                    rootwidth: 'Auto',
                    backgroundColor: 'AliceBlue',
                    botAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/ink169.png?size=64',
                    bubbleBackground: 'rgba(46, 115, 187, .2)',
                    //botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
                    userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/FreddieK01.png?size=64',
                    bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(141, 252, 237, .7)',
                    bubbleMaxWidth: 600,
                    hideUploadButton: true,
                    // userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
                };

                );
            botConnection.postActivity({ type: "event", from: user, name: "firstMessage", value: "ping" }).subscribe(id => console.log("Conversation updated"));
        </script>
```

Here is the code we changed from (old code that doesn't send welcome message but is styled)

```
                const styleOptions = {
                    rootwidth: 'Auto',
                    backgroundColor: 'AliceBlue',
                    botAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/ink169.png?size=64',
                    bubbleBackground: 'rgba(46, 115, 187, .2)',
                    //botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
                    userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/FreddieK01.png?size=64',
                    bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(141, 252, 237, .7)',
                    bubbleMaxWidth: 600,
                    hideUploadButton: true,
                    // userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
                };

                window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                    {
                        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                            secret: ''
                        }),
                        styleOptions
                    },
                    document.getElementById('webchat')
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the `WebChat.renderWebChat()` or `ReactDOM.render()` versions (v4) of [Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). The `BotChat.App()` (v3) is deprecated and no longer supported by Microsoft. In addition, v4 Web Chat has a significant amount of functionality built into it which v3 lacks. You can reference the full range of samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples#samples-list).

That being said, either will work with your bot whether you are running the older BotBuilder v3 SDK or the newer v4.

Regarding sending a welcome message, the [04.api/a.welcome-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) sample details how to set this up.

In short, you would send an event from Web Chat to your bot when  the two connect via Web Chat's `store`. When your bot receives the event, it is triggered to send the welcome message to display to the user.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
  // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
    dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'webchat/join',
        value: { language: window.navigator.language }
      }
    });
  }

  return next(action);
});

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    store
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

Hope of help!